Linux find - exclude parent directory with some pattern
How I can exclude some parent directory from find output, if it contains some sub-directory name pattern? I have similar directory tree:
fnd
|-- aaa
|   `-- 2023.11.12
|-- bbb
|   |-- 2023.12.12
|   `-- 2024.03.03
`-- ccc

When I've running command:
find fnd/* -type d -not -name "2024*" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -prune

it give me:
fnd/aaa/2023.11.12
fnd/bbb/2023.12.12

But I needed only directory, that not contain some subdirectory. So how I can see only
fnd/aaa/2023.11.12

?

If you just wanted that specific directory name, then the following would work:
find fnd/* -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec test ! -d "{}/2024.03.03" \; -print

Output:
fnd/aaa/2023.11.12

That uses the test command to check if any of the directories returned by find don't have a subdirectory called 2024.03.03 and prints any that don't. There are only two directories returned and only one does not have a subdirectory with that name so it is printed.
What you want is to print the directory whose name doesn't begin with the pattern (or string) 2024 regardless of what else is contained afterwards. The above won't function by adding a wildcard * because test only looks for the exact directory name and won't expand wildcards so the following will return both directories due to neither containing a subdirectory called 2024*. That is what you don't want as exhibited below:
find fnd/* -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec test ! -d "{}/2024*" \; -print

Output:
fnd/aaa/2023.11.12
fnd/bbb/2023.12.12

It looks as though one can add if [ ! -d {}/2024* ]; then echo {}; fi \; to the -exec switch for find but that won't work because if is a shell keyword and -exec can only execute commands and scripts.
The simplest way to get what you want is to create a script containing the following:
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d $1/2024* ]; then echo $1; fi

And then use the following command:
find fnd/* -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec ./script {} \;

Output:
fnd/aaa/2023.11.12

What that does is to exec ./script and use the output of find which is {} as the first and only argument which then uses an if..then statement to see if the directories don't begin with the string 2024 and prints the one that doesn't which gives your expected output.
To verify that it is working, create a directory inside of fnd/aaa/2023.11.12 called 2024.04.04, for example, then run the find command that I specified and it will output nothing because both directories contain a subdirectory beginning with the string 2024.
Lastly, to clarify one detail, you have in your question that you don't want it to contain the pattern 2024 but I mention it as not beginning with the pattern 2024 because that is what your wildcard is doing due to you having it as 2024*. To have it as not containing the string 2024 at all as you have stated, use *2024*.
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d $1/*2024* ]; then echo $1; fi

